# sql self join CTE or other way

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a column which shows the difference between the average of two consecutive days of a table, I tried to do this with a CTE query:

```
with aggregate
as
(
select date  
        ,y
        ,z
       ,avg(x) as vwap  
from table a  
where z = 1
group by date,y,z
)
select aggregate.date
       ,aggregate.vwap - aggregate2.vwap
from aggregate
inner join aggregate aggregate2
on date = dateadd(day,-1,aggregate2.date) and aggregate.y = aggregate2.y
```

this Query takes 29 second to run, while the first select takes only 2 second and returns only 2000 rows.

what is a more efficient way to do this?
does it maybe make sense to create a view of the first query?

Thanks!

So I found out the lag/lead is not an option as my server is actually from 2008 and only the management studio is 2012, anyone have an idea how to do this efficient?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? With 2012 you could use LAG() and window functions with OVER()

Comment: the database is of only working days, so lag would also show the monday/friday difference which I don't want to include. but thank you!

Comment: If your table does **not** include the weekend days, LAG() would be perfect, wouldn't it? Or do you evaluate Friday to Monday as not consecutive? In this case you could combine LAG() with CASE on the weekday...

Comment: What is "z"? Since it's part of the group by but not of the join clause. Does the whole query give more rows then the CTE and is that intended?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is just a differenct column I want to possibly filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I think that for every join or aggregate in the final select the whole CTE was rerun. When I created a temporary table of the CTE results and than run my Inner join final query on that the speed increased by factor 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new SQL analytic functions [SQL Lead()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) and [Lag() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lag-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-previous-values.aspx) introduced with SQL Server 2012

Please check following SELECT statement

```
;with [aggregate] as (
    select 
        [date], avg(x) as vwap
    from table a  
    group by date,y,z
)
select
    [date],
    vwap,
    previous = lag(vwap,1,null) over (order by date),
    [next] = lead(vwap,1,null) over (order by date)
from [aggregate]
```

You can improve the above SELECT with adding difference calculation too

```
;with [aggregate] as (
    select 
        [date], avg(x) as vwap
    from table a  
    group by date,y,z
)
select
    [date],
    vwap,
    previous = lag(vwap,1,null) over (order by date),
    prev_diff = vwap - (lag(vwap,1,null) over (order by date)),
    [next] = lead(vwap,1,null) over (order by date),
    next_diff = vwap - (lead(vwap,1,null) over (order by date))
from [aggregate]
```

Comment: thank you very much, however I just found out that just the management Studio we run is 2012 and the server itself is 2008.... any other way how to do this?

Comment: you can add a row_number() field based on aggregate values ordered by date fields. Then join the CTE with itself. Use one field row_number to join 1 plus for next day value. You can use 1 less for previous day.

Comment: yeah I think I got it, but the problem is not to do it, but the problem is more that the inner join takes between 1-2 minutes to run. I was wondering why your method would be faster than the inner join on my date column?

Comment: Did you check the execution plan, I guess most of the time spent is on the aggregation part. If so, you can create an index on date field with including column x

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SQL Server version which is before SQL Server 2012, you can use CTE's joining itself instead of LEAD() and LAG() analytic functions

Here is a sample

```
;with [aggregate] as (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By [date]) rn,
        [date], 
        avg(x) as vwap
    from a  
    group by date--,y,z
)
select
    curr.[date],
    curr.vwap,
    previous = prev.vwap,
    prev_diff = curr.vwap - prev.vwap,
    [next] = nxt.vwap,
    next_diff = curr.vwap - nxt.vwap
from [aggregate] curr
left join [aggregate] prev on curr.rn = (prev.rn + 1)
left join [aggregate] nxt on (curr.rn + 1) = nxt.rn
```

You can find a similar case explained in following SQL tutorial: [Select Next and Previous Row with Current Row using SQL CTE and Row_Number() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-select-previous-and-next-rows-with-current-row-in-tsql.aspx)

One important note, in your query I see group by clause with additional fields.

You should be adding those in Row_Number() code instead of

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By [date]) rn,
```

as follows

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By y,z Order By [date]) rn,
```

Comment: Yeah I have been trying something like this but than with date = dateadd(day,-1,date) as the self join, why would your self join on row number be faster than this?