# Self join on CTE

Tags: t-sql

I have doubts about the execution of an auto `join` on cte:

```html
;with data as
(
    select col1, col2, …, Weighting 
    from maTable
       some joins … (on EAV modele :( )
    where ...
)
select * form data t1
    left join data t2
         on t1.id = t2.id
         and t1.Weighting > t2.Weighting
```

The CTE will return all valid data, the self join will get the most recent values.

Will `SQL Server` scan `maTable` two times, or place the result in memory and use it for the join?

The execution plan shows that it scans my index two times...

What is the best way to do this with less impact on cpu and io?

Using a
 - temp table instead of CTE is quicker but use more CPU and IO
 - var table instead of CTE is longer and use a lot more CPU and IO

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok seems that cte query is rerun :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837935/sql-self-join-cte-or-other-way

Comment: *"What is the best way to do this with less impact on cpu and io?"*  Depends entirely on what you are actually trying to do.  Your current script is essentially pointless...